# PySide error (on mac, python 3.6)

Tags: macos, python-3.x, qt, pyside, spyder

I have updated qt from anaconda
conda update qt 
and a list of new packages have been installed and several update performed:
The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

```
dbus:      1.10.22-h50d9ad6_0   
expat:     2.2.4-h8f26bf8_1     
gettext:   0.19.8.1-hb0f4f8b_2  
glib:      2.53.6-ha08cb78_1    
libcxx:    4.0.1-h579ed51_0     
libcxxabi: 4.0.1-hebd6815_0     
libedit:   3.1-hb4e282d_0       
libffi:    3.2.1-hd939716_3     
ncurses:   6.0-ha932d30_1       
pcre:      8.41-h29eefc5_0
```

The following packages will be UPDATED:

```
conda:     4.3.29-py36hbf39572_0 --> 4.3.30-py36h173c244_0
icu:       54.1-0                --> 58.2-hea21ae5_0      
libpng:    1.6.27-0              --> 1.6.32-hce72d48_2    
pyqt:      5.6.0-py36_2          --> 5.6.0-py36he5c6137_6 
python:    3.6.0-0               --> 3.6.3-h6804ab2_0     
qt:        5.6.2-2               --> 5.6.2-h9975529_14    
readline:  6.2-2                 --> 7.0-h81b24a6_3       
sqlite:    3.13.0-0              --> 3.20.1-h900c3b0_1    
tk:        8.5.18-0              --> 8.6.7-hcdce994_1     
xz:        5.2.2-1               --> 5.2.3-ha24016e_1     
zlib:      1.2.8-3               --> 1.2.11-h60db283_1
```

Then I have update to spyder 3.2.4.
At the end of this procedure, I cannot open anaconda-navigator anymore, the error being on my mac OSX10.8.5 with python 3.6:

File "//anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qtpy/**init**.py", line 119, in 
    from PySide import **version** as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//anaconda/bin/anaconda-navigator", line 6, in 
    sys.exit(anaconda_navigator.app.main.main())
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/app/main.py", line 47, in main
    from anaconda_navigator.utils.logs import clean_logs
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/utils/**init**.py", line 15, in 
    from qtpy.QtGui import QIcon
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qtpy/**init**.py", line 125, in 
    raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found')
qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found

What can I do now?

Comment: What is your macOS version?

Comment: MacOS 10.8.5. Note that I had no problems in update qt on another mac with Sierra, macOS 10.12.6.

Comment: Ok, that could be the problem. The very latest (from two months ago or so) Anaconda Qt builds only support macOS 10.9 or higher. So you should roll back to a previous Qt build to see if that fixes this.

Comment: ok, thanks, good to know. I recovered previous version of qt and now everything works fine again.